# magento remove /home from url

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect, url-rewrite

I am trying to configure how to redirect my Magento website from "www.mywebsite.com/home" to base url "www.mywebsite.com", it always redirecting to www.mywebsite.com/home

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I got error at the browser says "The page isn't redirecting properly"

I don't know where to change it to only "http://www.mywebsite.com/"

I will have problem with SEO if it not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Khali. please try this

find  `RewriteEngine on`  at  .htaccess then file added below code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourwebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You may need to make alternations based on whether or not you require support for https.

Comment: Thanks moose, I tried that, It still coming back to http://www.cabas-durables.fr/accueil

Comment: the problem I found is the url is taking the category page instead of the cms home page url, I don't know why